# Как получить строку со следующей версией | MySql

Tags: mysql

В базе хранятся записи версий в формате x.x.x
Как можно получить запись со следующей версией, зная существующую?
Например у нас версия 0.0.1, нам нужна следующая которая доступна, т.е. 0.0.2 или если её нет, то 0.0.3 и т.д.

Мой запрос работает неправильно:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM table
WHERE version > 0.0.1
ORDER BY id ASC
```

Таким образом он вернет 0.0.2, но если в базе есть 1.2.1, то он вернет ее, что является ошибкой.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение найдено

```
SELECT
    MIN(version) AS version,
    ...
FROM table
WHERE version > 0.0.1
ORDER BY id ASC
```